# How to increment the number in a String by 1?

Tags: java, string, increment

I have a below String as -

```
String current_version = "v2";
```

And here version can be either of these string as well - `v3` or `v4` or `v10` or `v100` or `v500` or `v1000`

Now I am looking to increment the current_version from `v2` to `v3`. Meaning I always need to increment the current_version by 1.

If current_version is `v5`, then I will increment it to `v6`.

How can I do this with a String?

NOTE:-

I am getting `current_version` string value from some method which will always return me like this v2, v3, v4 only..

Comment: Do you mean `String current_version = "v2"` (with quotes)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to parse the number after the v as an int and increment it by 1, just do so by substringing, adding 1 to the number and concatenating the resulting incremented number back into a string with "v" prepended:

```
    String version = "v1";
    String newVersion = "v" + (Integer.parseInt(version.substring(1,version.length()))+1);
    System.out.println(newVersion);
```

Alternatively, you could keep track of the current version in an `int`, increment that and construct your new `String` by appending that int to a "v", without having to call `substring()`.

Answer (score 11):

I will suggest you to store the version in an int. so the codes will be following

```
int versionNumber = 1;
```

whenever you want to increment just increment it using

```
versionNumber++;
```

and to print or store as a complete version do following

```
String version = "v" + versionNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
int version = Integer.parseInt(current_version.replace("v", ""));
```

then you can increment it and add a get `"v" + current_version`

Answer (score 1):

If your format ever changes, this allows for a bit more flexibility:

```
String version = "v1234";
System.out.println("v" + (Integer.parseInt(version.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")) + 1));
```

Use a regex to drop all non-digits, add one to the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String oldVersion = "v100";
    String[] splitString = oldVersion.split("v");
    int newVersion = Integer.valueOf(splitString[1])+1;
    String completeNewVersion = splitString[0] + newVersion;
    System.out.print(completeNewVersion);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't store the version as an int and add the char 'v' when displaying the version?
If you wish to do it with a String, you can make a substring of the initial one, parse it to int and after that add to'v' the result.

```
 currentVersion = "v" + (Integer.parseInt(currentVersion .substring(1)) + 1);
```

Comment: That's one way. I am not storing this v2 in my code base, this string `v2` I am getting as it is from some method.. So I need to increment it by 1.

Comment: Does not answer the question and should be a comment

Comment: Do you always know what is the format of your string? Does it always be vXXX ?

Comment: Yes it will always be vXXXXXX.

Answer (score 0):

This method is a bit more complex, but it is able to handle any kind of version-string. The *currentVersion* might already have a number defined, or it might be implicitly 1, major and minor version numbers can be present, only the last one is incremented.

The string is searched from the end until the first non-digit character is found. The *versionNumber* is computed as an integer and finally increased.

Then the *newVersion* is created. If the incremented versionNumber is 1, it means that the original String did not end in a number. In this case the versioning is started with *_v2*

```
String currentVersion = "test_v123.432";
int versionNumber = 0;
int power = 1;
int index = currentVersion.length()-1;
while (index > 0) { // get the last chars as long as they are digits
    char digit = currentVersion.charAt(index);
    if ((digit >= '0') && (digit <= '9')) {
        versionNumber += (digit -'0') * power;
        power = power * 10;
        index --;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
versionNumber ++;
String newVersion = currentVersion.substring(0, index+1) + ((versionNumber == 1)? "_v2": versionNumber);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want another solution you can use this :

```
uint8_t versionNumber = 1;
char version[40];
sprintf(version,"v %d",versionNumber);
```

And you increment your variable "versionNumber" whenever you want !